# RN RTL :The layout keeps the RTL without changing it to the LTR even if you force it to change the layout

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When I create a project for the project to support the RTL, according to what is mentioned in the [Decumnant](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps) , it gives me this eroor

```
 error: cannot find symbol
  I18nUtil mI18nUtil = I18nUtil.getInstance();
  ^
 symbol:   class I18nUtil
location: class MainApplication
```

. After searching, I found that I should add this

```
import com.facebook.react.modules.i18nmanager.I18nUtil;
   import android.os.Bundle;
```

but get to me this error

```
error: cannot find symbol
      mI18nUtil.forceRTL(context,true);
                         ^
  symbol:   variable context
  location: class MainApplication
```

and After searching agin , I found that I should replace `context`  to  `getApplicationContext()`

In the Finally the project works for me, but the problem is that it keeps the project on RTL even though I am writing

```
    //on APP.js  
     if (lang == 'en') {
     I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
     I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
 
    }
      else{
    I18nManager.allowRTL(true);
    I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
     }
```

//my language here is English

[image]

my MainApplication code

```
package com.twinkle;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.config.ReactFeatureFlags;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.twinkle.newarchitecture.MainApplicationReactNativeHost;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;
import com.facebook.react.modules.i18nmanager.I18nUtil;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
      };

  private final ReactNativeHost mNewArchitectureNativeHost =
      new MainApplicationReactNativeHost(this);

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      return mNewArchitectureNativeHost;
    } else {
      return mReactNativeHost;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate();
     
    // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the TurboModule system
    ReactFeatureFlags.useTurboModules = BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
      I18nUtil mI18nUtil = I18nUtil.getInstance();
      mI18nUtil.forceRTL(getApplicationContext(),true);
      mI18nUtil.allowRTL(getApplicationContext(), true);
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.twinkle.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

}
```

and my useEffect on App.js

```
 useEffect(async () => {
    const lang = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@AppLang');

    if (lang) {
      AppLanguage.setLanguage(lang);
      if (lang == 'ar') {
        I18nManager.allowRTL(true);
        I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
      } else {
        I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
        I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
      }
    } else {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('@AppLang', 'en');
      AppLanguage.setLanguage('en');
    }
  }, []);
```

and my code in select language

```
onPress={async () => {
                  dispatch(setCurrentLanguage(selectedOption));
                  await AsyncStorage.setItem('@AppLang', selectedOption);

                  RNRestart.Restart();
}
```